# Differentiating between stacked parcel shapefile and general parcel shapefile using Python

Tags: python, shapefile, attribute-table, pyshp

I am totally new to this domain. I would like to detect stacked parcel shapefile and mapped respective data or outlines created to all stacked parcels. In a general case where only one parcel on land it's easy to map one to one mapping. But when one building apartment has 20 floors and each floor has a different parcel for this case I want to map data to each parcel like one to many relationship.

Is it possible in Python to get some differentiable data between stacked parcel shapefile and general shapefile?

Stacked parcel example :

[image]

Comment: You need to add a code attempt to your question or it will be closed. Which python library do you want to use? What do you mean by "detect", can you add a screenshot/drawing/etc. showing your desired results?

Comment: pyshp library want to use.

Comment: I would like to know what is different between general parcel shape file and stacked parcel shalefile.

Comment: I dont know pyshp but in ArcGIS I would Intersect the data with itself. Then you will get new polygons where they overlap.

Comment: Yeah ArcGIS has this feature to show this error data. But required to use either FME script or python to detect.

Comment: `pyshp` doesn't have such a functionality, it just reads and writes shapefile.  You may want to look at [`geopandas`](https://geopandas.org/mergingdata.html) library for that.